# While loop continues running even though it shouldn't

Tags: powershell

I'm creating regression using a while loop and some if statements in order to automate SQL testing, and everything seems to be functioning properly except for some reason when the $Phase is set equal to 4, (which should break the loop), it seems to run again, resetting the $Phase variable. There is no code in the "SQLQueryKafkaTesting" Function that should be affecting the $Phase or $Choice values except for this loop.

```
if ($Global:Dashboard -eq "KafkaDashboard_Headless") {
        while ($Phase -le 3) {
            $Choice++
            # max amount of choices for phase 1 (CDC-DB) exceeds here
            if ($Phase -eq 1 -and $Choice -gt 0) {
                SQLQueryKafkaTesting 2 0
            }
            # make sure we loop through all the choices for phase 2 (CDC-Tables), here 2 choices is the upper-bound exclusive
            if ($Phase -eq 2 -and $Choice -lt 2 ) {
                SQLQueryKafkaTesting 2 $Choice
                
            }
            # when there are no longer any phase 2 choices, go to next phase
            elseif ($Phase -eq 2 -and $Choice -ge 2) {
                SQLQueryKafkaTesting 3 0
            }
            # make sure we loop through all the choices for phase 3 (Diffs), here 2 choices is the upper-bound exclusive
            if ($Phase -eq 3 -and $Choice -lt 2 ) {
                SQLQueryKafkaTesting 3 $Choice
                
            }
            # phase 3 is the last phase, so once there are no more choices, we can break the loop
            elseif ($Phase -eq 3 -and $Choice -ge 2) {
                $Phase = 4
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `$Phase` is `1` or `2` at the start of the loop, then it'll never update. Perhaps you wanna change the last condition from `$Phase -eq 3 -and $Choice -ge 2` to just `$Choice -ge 2`?

Comment: Alternatively, use `while ($true)` and `break` to break out of the loop.

Comment: This is a good occassion to start learning how to use a debugger. With a debugger, you can run your code step by step, watch the variables at each step and see if they match your expectations. This might sound tedious (and it sometimes is), but a debugger really is the right tool for solving problems like this. VSCode with PowerShell addin provides a really nice debugging experience, but you may also use the (somewhat deprecated) PowerShell ISE if you only use Windows PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen When the `$Phase` starts at 1, it will recall the function and eventually get back to the while loop with phase set to 2 triggered here `if ($Phase -eq 1 -and $Choice -gt 0) {
                SQLQueryKafkaTesting 2 0
            }`
Each choice has a different phase so I cannot just check the choices

Comment: @zett42 I tried stepping through with the debugger and couldn't figure it out haha, so I posted here to see if anyone had any other Ideas, didn't seem clear to me why when set to phase 4 the while loop didn't end

Comment: you know what, I think it's an asynchronous issue here, haven't dealt with one of those in a while let me try and check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, needed to call the `SQLQueryKafkaTesting` in a seperate function instead of within itself, allowing me to move the while loop outside of the function itself, and allow adjust the parameters that make the loop run within the `SQLQueryKafkaTesting` function.